# Angular: access pretty URL in test mode

Tags: angularjs, routes, gulp, reload

Building an angular app, I activated the html5Mode. This way I have pretty URL like

```
localhost:3002/myPage/12345
```

instead of

```
localhost:3002/#/myPage/12345
```

It is cool, but pretty URLs only works when accessed from a link. Otherwise I get error:

```
Cannot GET /myPage/12345
```

It sounds logical, as I should redirect any request to the / and pass parameters/an URL that angular can interprete directly.

It can be done in an external server, but I'd like in a test environment. This is because I use gulp with detection of changes and autoreload, so now the autoreload doesn't work any more (as it tries to reload the pretty URL).

Comment: What are the details of your test environment? what are you using to serve the site?

Comment: I use NodeJS with gulp and browsersync